# MALFORMED_QUERY: duplicate alias: Email

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx, salesforce-id

Gentelmen I know you have more than free time for challenges like this
I have downloaded all metadata for reports and rep types
I have found one specific fields that is in there
**Now I need to get all creators/modifiers of these reports**
Doesn't matter that I hit SOQL character limit 20,000 which is really 4000 for WHERE CLAUSE
I have more than 2000 lines and ~70000 - doesn't matter.
**All I need is to get emails from creator or last modified but if I ran this query**

```
select CreatedBy.Email, COUNT(CreatedById), LastModifiedById 
from Report
where DeveloperName IN
(LOTS OF REPORTS BY DEV NAME,
LOTS OF REPORTS BY DEV NAME)
group by CreatedBy.Email, LastModifiedById
```

Above code works but if I want **both emails** fields I am interested in then I get

```
select CreatedBy.Email, COUNT(CreatedById), LastModifiedBy.Email
from Report
where DeveloperName IN
(LOTS OF REPORTS BY DEV NAME,
LOTS OF REPORTS BY DEV NAME)
group by CreatedBy.Email, LastModifiedBy.Email
```

I will get an
MALFORMED_QUERY: duplicate alias: Email

I have went through ALIAS keywordk in SOQL & SOSL guide but without success.

Comment: Try actually applying aliases: `SELECT COUNT(CreatedById), CreatedBy.Email CreatedEmail, LastModifiedBy.Email ModifiedEmail FROM Report ...` and see if that sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried to do it by aliasing but somehow I got errors and then I did this:

```
select CreatedBy.Email, COUNT(CreatedById), LastModifiedBy.Email **aliasEmail**
from Report 
where DeveloperName IN (......reports)

group by CreatedBy.Email, LastModifiedBy.Email
```